# Strip html from the title="" and alt="" attributes of a link based on a css class

Tags: jquery

I need to strip html  from the title="" and alt="" attributes of a link carrying a specific css class.

The code is being generated by a CMS and having no access to the page code, only the head, I'm thinking jQuery might be a good solution.

I've got this far

```
function removeAllHtml() {
    $(".example_1").html( $(".example_1").text() );
};
removeAllHtml();
```

But I have no idea how to limit it based on a css class or to specify only the alt and title attributes. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're saying the CMS is outputting HTML tags *inside* these attributes?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes, it's actually a bug I'm expecting it to be fixed in due time but this could take months, so I'm seeking other solutions. Basically the CMS is displaying a random image and a description with html which is contained in a text file taken from a folder. The problem is whomever developed the functionality implemented code to strip the html from the alt and title tags but it isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to have the title and alt tags cleaned of any HTML.  You could iterate over all the elements with the class, replacing the title and alt attributes of each with the text extracted from the existing element.

```
$(function() {
    $('.someclass').each( function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            title = $this.attr('title'),
            alt = $this.attr('alt');
        $this.attr('title',$(title).text())
             .attr('alt',$(alt).text();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
$(".example_1").each(
    function(){
        $(this).attr({'title' : '', 'alt' : ''});
    });
```

[Demo at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/R6PEW/1/).